# Editing child array objects in Angular 2

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I'm new to Angular and have hit a wall in my project which i'm hoping some of you more experienced devs can help me smash through!

I have a JSON file which is called by a service. This data is then injected into the component via my interface where I am using a custom Dictionary class for the 'lists' (list1, list2 etc) i'm looking to let the user edit.

Everything was all good until I had to start trying to use the 'nested' lists from my JSON file. I cannot find a way to use this in my component so that the user can edit the strings.

My JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "insurer": "My Insurer",
    "product": "Healthier Solutions",
    "heading1": "Insurance",
    "heading2": "Insurance Product Information Document",
    "heading3": "What is the type of insurance?",
    "heading4": "What is insured?",
    "heading5": "What is NOT insured?",
    "heading6": "Are there restrictions on my cover?",
    "heading7": "Where am I covered?",
    "heading8": "What are my obligations?",
    "heading9": "When and how do I pay?",
    "heading10": "When does my cover start and end?",
    "heading11": "How do I cancel my contract?",
    "subHeading1": "Insurance Company",
    "subHeading2": "Healthier Solutions",
    "textBox1": "Private Medical Insurance",
    "textBox2": "You will have access to Aviva’s Key Hospital list in the UK.",
    "textBox3": "Monthly by direct debit. The first payment will be collected within 14 days of setting up the policy. The following payments will be collected monthly thereafter.",
    "textBox4": "The policy will start on your chosen start date and will end exactly 12 months later.",
    "textBox5": "Please contact...",
    "list1": {
      "item1": "In and day patient hospital charges",
      "item2": "In and day patient diagnostic tests",
      "item3": "In and day patient diagnostic scans",
      "item4": "In and day patient specialist fees",
      "item5": "In and day patient radiotherapy",
      "item6": "In and day patient chemotherapy",
      "item7": "Outpatient specialist consultations",
      "item8": "Outpatient diagnostic tests",
      "item9": "Outpatient diagnostic scans",
      "item10": "Outpatient radiotherapy",
      "item11": "Outpatient chemotherapy"
    },
    "list2": {
      "item1": "Routine monitoring of conditions",
      "item2": "Pre-existing conditions",
      "item3": "GP consultations and treatment",
      "item4": "Emergency treatment",
      "item5": "Chronic conditions (e.g. the management of incurable conditions such as asthma, diabetes, arthritis)",
      "item6": "Self-inflicted conditions"
    },
    "list3": {
      "item1": "Outpatient psychiatric treatment limited to £2,000 a year",
      "item2": "Fees and charges by specialists are limited to Aviva’s fee guidelines"
    },
    "list4": {
      "item1": "You must be a UK resident.",
      "item2": "You must pay your monthly premiums in full and on time.",
      "item3": "You must be registered with a UK GP at the point of making a claim.",
      "item4": "You must ensure that all information that you provide is accurate and true to the best of your knowledge and belief."
    }
  }
]
```

My interface looks like this:

```
import {
  IDictionary
} from "../models/IDictionary";

export interface IProducts {
  id: number;
  insurer: string;
  product: string;

  heading1: string;
  heading2: string;
  heading3: string;
  heading4: string;
  heading5: string;
  heading6: string;
  heading7: string;
  heading8: string;
  heading9: string;
  heading10: string;
  heading11: string;

  subHeading1: string;
  subHeading2: string;

  textBox1: string;
  textBox2: string;
  textBox3: string;
  textBox4: string;
  textBox5: string;

  list1: IDictionary;
  list2: IDictionary;
  list3: IDictionary;
  list4: IDictionary;
}
```

Here is my custom dictionary class:

```
export interface IDictionary {
  add(key: string, value: any): void;
  remove(key: string): void;
  containsKey(key: string): boolean;
  keys(): string[];
  values(): any[];

  item1: string;
  item2: string;
  item3: string;
  item4: string;
  item5: string;
  item6: string;
  item7: string;
  item8: string;
  item9: string;
  item10: string;
  item11: string;
}
```

Here is what my component uses to enable the user to edit the data via a HTML input by importing my interface and using my 'edit' model:

```
editProduct(k:any) {
    this.edit.heading1 = this.products[k].heading1;
    this.edit.heading2 = this.products[k].heading2;
    this.edit.heading3 = this.products[k].heading3;
    this.edit.heading4 = this.products[k].heading4;
    this.edit.heading5 = this.products[k].heading5;
    this.edit.heading6 = this.products[k].heading6;
    this.edit.heading7 = this.products[k].heading7;
    this.edit.heading8 = this.products[k].heading8;
    this.edit.heading9 = this.products[k].heading9;
    this.edit.heading10 = this.products[k].heading10;
    this.edit.heading11 = this.products[k].heading11;
    this.edit.subHeading1 = this.products[k].subHeading1;
    this.edit.subHeading2 = this.products[k].subHeading2;
    this.edit.textBox1 = this.products[k].textBox1;
    this.edit.textBox2 = this.products[k].textBox2;
    this.edit.textBox3 = this.products[k].textBox3;
    this.edit.textBox4 = this.products[k].textBox4;
    this.edit.textBox5 = this.products[k].textBox5;

    this.edit.list1item1 = this.products[k].list1.item1;

    this.myValue = k;
}
updateProduct() {
    let k = this.myValue;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
        if (i === k) {
            this.products[i] = this.edit;
            this.edit = {};
        }
    }
    this.showSuccessAlertMessage = "This product has been successfully updated.";
}
```

I'm looking to do something like the above - 'this.edit.list1item1 = this.products[k].list1.item1;', but that is not working.

Really hope that makes sense please do let me know if it doesn't and i'll do my best to explain it clearer.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the issue you are having? And what is the argument `k` you are sending into `editProduct`?

Comment: isn't better do `this.edit = this.products[k]`?

Comment: do homework yourself.

Comment: haha... I've already spent a few hours trying to figure it out and searching the web but unfortunately no luck.Thought maybe I should put my pride aside and ask for help directly :)